# how to change turn speed AI enemy

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have enemy AI and patrol points to which he moves, when he reaches the point, he starts turning to the next point and moves towards it. So it turns too slowly, how to speed up this turn?
I used transform.LookAt() but it rotates instantly.

```
[SerializeField] private NavMeshAgent _agent;
[SerializeField] private List<Transform> _targets;
private float _patrolDistance;
private int index;

private void FixedUpdate()
{
    _patrolDistance = Vector3.Distance(_agent.transform.position, _agent.pathEndPosition);

    if (_patrolDistance < 0.1f)
    {
        RandomTarget();
        transform.LookAt(_targets[index]);
    }
    MovePatrolPoint();
}

private void RandomTarget()
{
    index = Random.Range(0, _targets.Count);
}

private void MovePatrolPoint()
{
    _agent.SetDestination(_targets[index].position);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can use alternatives like `Quaternion.Slerp` and `Quaternion.LookRotation` for smoother rotations

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this with a slerp and controlling the speed with a variable multiplied times the delta time.

```
    [SerializeField] private NavMeshAgent _agent;
    [SerializeField] private List<Transform> _targets;
    [SerializeField] private float Speed = 1;
    private float _patrolDistance;
    private Transform TargetTransform;
    private Vector3 Target => TargetTransform.position;
    private void Update()
    {
        CheckTargetDistance();
    }

    private void CheckTargetDistance()
    {
        _patrolDistance = Vector3.Distance(_agent.transform.position, _agent.pathEndPosition);

        if (_patrolDistance < 0.1f)
        {
            RandomTarget();
        }
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        LookAtTarget();
        MovePatrolPoint();
    }

    private void RandomTarget()
    {
        int index = Random.Range(0, _targets.Count);
        TargetTransform = _targets[index];
    }

    private void MovePatrolPoint()
    {
        _agent.SetDestination(Target);
    }
    private void LookAtTarget()
    {
        Quaternion lookRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(Target - transform.position);
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, lookRotation, Speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
```

Comment: oh my god, thank you very much, it works well, but I don't understand why add update if there is already fixedupdate

Comment: I suppose you could do it all in fixedUpdate. If you choose to do that make sure you use Time.fixedDeltaTime as the rates of each update is different. When using a rigid body you want the force applied in the fixed update. It's a habit of mine to update values in the update and apply movements with those values in the fixed update.